# Performance issue with cloud firestore

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developping a Reactjs app linked to cloud firestore, usually it works fast and really fast. In one of my view, I need to change the status of the command for any item in the list of items, the first time I change the status, it's fast, the second time it's a bit slower and it keeps getting slower and slower until it'unusable.

A workaround would be to reload the page as soon as the status change but I would like to know why this problem occurs.

Here is the view in question

```
import '../../App.css';
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import firebase from '../../firestore';
import { languageContext } from '../../context/LanguageContext';
import { absoluteLanguageContext } from '../../context/LanguageContext';
import {userRole} from '../../repostirories/UserRepository';
import 'react-dropdown/style.css';
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown';
import './CommandListView.css'
var db = firebase.firestore();

function CommandList() {
  const [commands, setCommands] = useState (null);
  const {language} = useContext(languageContext);
  const {absoluteLanguage} = useContext(absoluteLanguageContext);
  const commandPath = "/events/"+ userRole.substr(0,20) +"/menus/"+ userRole.substr(20, 20)  + "/commands/";
  const options = [
    {value: 1, label: '1'},
    {value: 2, label: '2'},
    {value: 3, label: '3'},
    {value: 4, label: '4'},
];
const optionsDictionary = [
  'A valider','En Préparation', 'Prêt', 'Délivré', 'Annulé'
]
  //Import the authorized commands from firebase
  useEffect(() => {
  async function InitCommands(){
    db.collection(commandPath).onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
      var commandList = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
          if (doc.exists){
              // Convert to command object
            var command;
            command = doc.data();
            command.key = doc.id;
            commandList.push(command);
            
          }
          else {
            console.log("No such document!")
        }})
        if(commandList.length !== 0){
            setCommands(commandList);
          }
      });
  }
  InitCommands();
  }, [commands, commandPath, language, absoluteLanguage]);

  const changeStatus = (id, status) =>{
    console.log(id + status.label)
    db.collection(commandPath).doc(id).set({
      commandStatus: status.value,
    }, { merge: true })
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      {commands === null? null : commands.map((command) => 
      <div key={command.key} >
        <div>
          <div style={{fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "24px", textAlign: 'center'}}> Commande N°  { ' ' + command.number} </div>
          
          <div style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>
          
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-container-command-2">
          <div style={{width:"23px"}}>
            {command.itemQuantities.map((quantity,index) =>
              <div key={index}>{quantity}x</div>
            )}
          </div>
          <div style={{width: '65%'}}>
            {command.itemNames.map((name,index) =>
                <div key={index}>{name.substring(0,25)}</div>
            )}
          </div>
          <div style={{textAlign: 'right', width:'20%'}}>
            {command.itemPrices.map((price,index) =>
                <div key={index}>{price} CHF</div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-container-command-1">
          Statut :  
          <div style={{width: '60px', paddingLeft: '15px', paddingRight: '15px', height: '60px'}}>
            <Dropdown
              arrowClosed={<span style={{padding:'0px'}} />}
              id={command.key}
              placeholder={(String)(command.commandStatus)}
              value={command.commandStatus}
              options={options}
              onChange={o => {changeStatus(command.key, o)}}
            ></Dropdown>
          </div>
          <div style={{width: '50%'}}>
            { ' ' + optionsDictionary[command.commandStatus]}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-container-command-3">
          <div style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>Total de la commande : {command.totalPrice} CHF</div>
          {command.paymentStatus===false?
            <div style={{color: 'red', fontWeight:"bolder"}}>A payer</div>:
            <div style={{color: 'green', fontWeight:"bolder"}}> Payé </div>}
        </div>
      </div>
      )}
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default CommandList;
```

Comment: That sounds unexpected. 1) Can you add some logging to the code to show the performance degradation, and add that updates code and its output to the question? 2) Is the client connecting to the backend? Or is it running offline?

Comment: 2) the client is connecting to the backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a memory leak because the firestore listener isn't closed the following code solve the problem:

```
import '../../App.css';
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import firebase from '../../firestore';
import { languageContext } from '../../context/LanguageContext';
import { absoluteLanguageContext } from '../../context/LanguageContext';
import {userRole} from '../../repostirories/UserRepository';
import 'react-dropdown/style.css';
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown';
import './CommandListView.css'
var db = firebase.firestore();

function CommandList() {
  const [commands, setCommands] = useState (null);
  const {language} = useContext(languageContext);
  const {absoluteLanguage} = useContext(absoluteLanguageContext);
  const commandPath = "/events/"+ userRole.substr(0,20) +"/menus/"+ userRole.substr(20, 20)  + "/commands/";
  const options = [
    {value: 1, label: '1'},
    {value: 2, label: '2'},
    {value: 3, label: '3'},
    {value: 4, label: '4'},
];
const optionsDictionary = [
  'A valider','En Préparation', 'Prêt', 'Délivré', 'Annulé'
]
  //Import the authorized commands from firebase
  useEffect(() => {

    let unsubscribe;
    async function InitCommands(){
      unsubscribe = db.collection(commandPath).onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
        var commandList = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            if (doc.exists){
              if(doc.id.length > 10) {
                // Convert to command object
                var command;
                command = doc.data();
                command.key = doc.id;
                commandList.push(command);
              }
            }
            else {
              console.log("No such document!")
          }})
          if(commandList.length !== 0){
            //sort the list by date hour
            commandList.sort((a, b)=> {
              return new Date(a.dateHour + 'Z') -  new Date(b.dateHour + 'Z')})
            setCommands(commandList)
          }
      });
    }
  InitCommands();
  return () => {unsubscribe()};

  }, [commandPath, language, absoluteLanguage]);

  const changeStatus = (id, status) =>{
    db.collection(commandPath).doc(id).set({
      commandStatus: status.value,
    }, { merge: true })
  }



  return (
    <div className="App">
      {commands === null? null : commands.map((command) =>
      <div key={command.key} >
        <div>
          <div style={{fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "24px", textAlign: 'center'}}> Commande N°  { ' ' + command.number} </div>

          <div style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-container-command-2">
          <div style={{width:"23px"}}>
            {command.itemQuantities.map((quantity,index) =>
              <div key={index}>{quantity}x</div>
            )}
          </div>
          <div style={{width: '65%'}}>
            {command.itemNames.map((name,index) =>
                <div key={index}>{name.substring(0,25)}</div>
            )}
          </div>
          <div style={{textAlign: 'right', width:'20%'}}>
            {command.itemPrices.map((price,index) =>
                <div key={index}>{price*command.itemQuantities[index]} CHF</div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-container-command-1">
          Statut :
          <div style={{verticalAlign: 'top'}}>
            <Dropdown
              className='dropdown'
              id={command.key}
              placeholder={(String)(command.commandStatus)}
              options={options}
              onChange={o => {changeStatus(command.key, o)}}
            ></Dropdown>
          </div>
          <div >
            { ' ' + optionsDictionary[command.commandStatus]}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-container-command-3">
          <div style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>Total de la commande : {command.totalPrice} CHF</div>
          {command.paymentStatus===false?
            <div style={{color: 'red', fontWeight:"bolder"}}>A payer</div>:
            <div style={{color: 'green', fontWeight:"bolder"}}> Payé </div>}
        </div>
      </div>
      )}
    </div>

  )
}

export default CommandList;
```

Here's the official documentation where you can find how to close a listener:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen